# LINQ statement to select the element which is deep inside the XML structure

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have XML which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <University>
          <Colleges>
            <College>
              <Id> Cambridge </Id>
              <Dept>
                <Id> Arts</Id>
              </Dept>
            </College>
            <College>
              <Id> Oxford</Id>
              <Dept>
                <Id> Philosophy </Id>
              </Dept>
            </College>
          </Colleges>
        </University>
```

I want to return the College based on the ID. In another scenario, I want to written just Id of the College.

I do not understand how to write LINQ statement to read Id directly. I can use `Descendants()` at every stage. But how to select the element which is deep inside the XML structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ-XML,

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
var results = doc.Root.Descendants("College")
              .Where(ele => ele.Element("Id").Value.Trim() == "Oxford");
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should use XPath. The syntax will be simpler than a pure Linq query :

```
using  System.Xml;
using  System.Xml.XPath;
...

public foo()
{
    XElement yourNode = XElement.Parse(yourstring);
    XElement college = root.XPathSelectElement("//College[Id='Oxford']");
}
```

If you can have College node at several position in the structure, the XPAth query `/University/Colleges/College[Id='OxFord']` will avoid conflicting issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's correct too. But unfortunately I cannot accept two responses as answer! So I just upvoted! Btw, I have not chosen this solution because I did not want to use XPath.